# How to custom validate FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

I'm building a reactive form with a FormArray which has FormGroups inside. Each FormGroup has 3 controls, from which two are dropdowns. I'd like to prevent the user to choose the same option multiple times in one of the dropdowns. I wrote a custom validator to achive this. It seems the validator works, because I enter the if clause where I return `{ 'subCategoryRepetition': true }`, but the form stays valid, the controll's error array is null.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the code:

**component.ts**

```
initEditUserDetialsForm() {
   this.editUserDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   ...
      categories: this.formBuilder.array(this.initSavedCategoryArray(this.merchantUserDetails.categories),
      checkSubCategoryRepetition.bind(checkSubCategoryRepetition))
   });
   this.categories = this.editUserDetailsForm.get('categories') as FormArray;
   this.removeCategoryDisabled = this.categories.length < 2;
}

initSavedCategoryArray(categories: CategoryDTO[]): FormGroup[] {
    let formGroupArray: FormGroup[] = [];
    categories.forEach((category, index) => {
        if (this.subCategories.length === 0) {
             this.subCategories.push(category.subCategory.mainCategory.subCategories);
        } else {
             this.subCategories.splice(index, 1, category.subCategory.mainCategory.subCategories);
        }
        formGroupArray.push(
             this.formBuilder.group({
                 mainCategory: [+category.subCategory.mainCategory.mainCategoryId, Validators.required],
                 subCategory: [+category.subCategory.subCategoryId, Validators.required],
                 donationPercentage: [category.donationPercentage, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100)]]
             })
         );
     });
     return formGroupArray;
}
```

**custom.validator.ts**

```
export function checkSubCategoryRepetition(formArray: FormArray) {
    let subCategoryIds: number[] = [];
    formArray.controls.forEach((formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        if (subCategoryIds.includes(+formGroup.controls.subCategory.value)) {
            console.log('repetition')
            return { 'subCategoryRepetition': true };
        }
        subCategoryIds.push(+formGroup.controls.subCategory.value);
    });
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forEach inside return will not break function excution, That's why you it's not working, try to for or reduce instead of forEach.

**Try this:**

```
export function checkSubCategoryRepetition(formArray: FormArray) {
    let subCategoryIds: number[] = [];
    const groups = formArray.controls;
    for(let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
      if (subCategoryIds.includes(+group[i].controls.subCategory.value)) {
            console.log('repetition')
            return { 'subCategoryRepetition': true };
        }
        subCategoryIds.push(+group[i].controls.subCategory.value);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about this. With a small modification it works as expected
`const groups = formArray.controls as FormGroup[];`